# Is there a way to exclude specific sites from remembering form history?

Tags: firefox, history

I'd like to keep form history turned on but exclude certain sites and haven't found a way.

Comment: Hmm - no "exceptions" button next to form history when you turn the settings to "Custom".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the FireFox plugin [HistoryBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/historyblock/) specific websites can be blocked from appearing in the browser's history.

Comment: Awesome.  I can't believe I was never able to track this down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While there is not a specific option (that I have found) you could just run that particular site under private browsing. Of course privacy is never guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so let's reply, my apologies. HistoryBlocks works great, thanks @Jura25.

This add-on actually **deletes** all references to the specified domain(s) from the history, even pre-dating the install. This behavior can be tested by blacklisting a domain, then un-blacklisting it: the related history entries don't seem to come back.

That's great if you want to prune your history a bit (eg. get rid of countless mail.google.com or facebook.com entries), but for other purposes you might want to be be careful though. To me this subtelty is not clearly expressed by the *blocked from appearing* notion, nor is the add-on page any clearer on that point.

Answer (score 0):

just as a append,if you are use `chrome`,Here is its equivalent replacement[History Blocker by Site](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-blocker-by-site/keamekimefemnbgegbfkdkmbomaahfai/related)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).